# Format in CSV OData endpoint output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, odata

I'm developing a OData endpoint using OData v4, Microsoft.aspnet.odata (v7.0.1); Microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata v5.3.1 and Microsoft.data.odata v5.6.0 as libs.
My question is the following: I have to export my found results in JSON (done of course) and in CSV.
Looks like you can't export directly in CSV, so, I thought to design it with a Task.
Is it the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance for your help,

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your data type returned, I found a nice example that describe how we can do that.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/customize-odata-payload-serialization-format-within-asp-net-core-odata/

It consist basically to add a new result format output (the default is JSON).

Answer (score -2):

Well, finally, I designed such an action:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Export()
{
    try
    {
        var uri = Request.RequestUri;
        return Redirect("https://"+uri.Host+"/Export/Index");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Of course, all will be done in controller Export to export my data as csv, I won't ask OData for this.
However, if you got a more elaborated solution, please share,

Kind regards,